# Manipulating complicated input array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dynamic form, and i don't know the name of the inputs except their array, and i need to relate them to each other.

For example, my form looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="43897346[TitleID]" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="11122223[FieldID]" value="36" />
<input type="hidden" name="11122223[FieldPermission]" value="read" />

<input type="hidden" name="44455566[FieldID]" value="37" />
<input type="hidden" name="44455566[FieldPermission]" value="write" />

<input type="hidden" name="77676667[TitleID]" value="2" />

<input type="hidden" name="88899000[FieldID]" value="38" />
<input type="hidden" name="88899000[FieldPermission]" value="write" />
```

and what im trying to do is to relate each input with the arrays of `FieldID and FieldPermission` to the `TitleID` that is above him, so my final result should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [FieldID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 36
                    [1] => 37
                )

            [FieldPermission] => Array
                (
                    [0] => read
                    [1] => write
                )

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [FieldID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 38
                )

            [FieldPermission] => Array
                (
                    [0] => write
                )

        )
)
```

NOTE: I don't know my input name's, i only know the array names.
I tried to do it like this:

```
$toInsert = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        $titleID = '';
        if(array_key_exists('TitleID',$v))
            $titleID = $v['TitleID'];
        if(array_key_exists('FieldID',$v))
            $toInsert[ $titleID ]['FieldID'][] = $v['FieldID'];
        if(array_key_exists('FieldPermission',$v))
            $toInsert[ $titleID ]['FieldPermission'][] = $v['FieldPermission'];
}
```

But with no success.... any ideas?
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just made one small mistake: you're resetting `$titleID` to an empty string *every time around the loop*. You want the value to stay there until you next encounter a `'titleID'` value, so just take that line out (or do it once, before the loop, to set an initial value "just in case"):

```
$toInsert = array();
$titleID = '';
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        if(array_key_exists('TitleID',$v))
            $titleID = $v['TitleID'];
        if(array_key_exists('FieldID',$v))
            $toInsert[ $titleID ]['FieldID'][] = $v['FieldID'];
        if(array_key_exists('FieldPermission',$v))
            $toInsert[ $titleID ]['FieldPermission'][] = $v['FieldPermission'];
}
```

Here's [a live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jPZasi) to show you that it works.

Comment: oh god... that took me hours an i was one step from the final result.. thank you so much!